# Show task bar on all displays

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar

On windows 7 how do I display my task bar on all of monitors (3) ?

I found the below instructions online:

`Just right-click on the taskbar, head to Properties, and check the "Show Taskbar on All Displays" box. From there, you can tweak it to your liking—showing taskbar buttons on all taskbars, or only the monitor where the window is open`

But this option does not seem to exist on my version of windows, is there a hidden setting or something obvious I am missing ?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your Windows 7 and display driver are fully updated, then this feature
is not available in standard Windows 7.

Try the free
[Dual Monitor Taskbar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/?source=dlp),
which does Taskbar on the every monitor and more.

Comment: Ahh was hoping that wasn't the answer, I will check out the software later today. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. The program works nice and it is freeware. Only 2MB. It does require elevation to run, but I did a scan on VirusTotal, and it is safe to run.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is only available from Windows 8 and above. To use the feature with Windows 7 you need a third party app like DisplayFusion.

Comment: Commercial software.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: this only works well if your multiple monitors have the same orientation and resolution.

If you had the monitors setup through the Nvidia Control Panel
you may do this **even** with Windows 7:

- Open NVIDIA Control Panel
- Click on the Desktop drop down menu located at the top of the window
- Mouse over Surround Displays
- Uncheck 'Confine taskbar to single display'

Below is my desktop, I am using Windows 7 pro.

The first wallpaper is spread across 3 screens and the second is across my 4th
If I had the 4th monitor setup in a different orientation I could also have the taskbar run on it as well, For my current setup I only want the 3 monitors

[image]

PS. on NVIDIA Control panel Version 8.1.940.0 with a GTX 1050 Ti, this setting is elsewhere. Go to "3D settings" in the navigation bar on the left -> "Configure Surround, PhysX". The click the box "Span displays with with Surround". There you can choose displays which act together as one.

Comment: Unrelated but do you have a link to that wallpaper?

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B060G9iIgAEzGr7.jpg