# Show taskbar (system tray) icons on all displays

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar, notification-area

I am using multiple displays. While the taskbar is visible on all displays, the icons and the notification area (colloquially known as *system tray* or *systray*) are only shown on the main display. Is it possible to show them on all displays?

[image: visible taskbar icons on main display]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1382883/show-task-bar-on-all-displays

Comment: @Sanu_012 That's about an issue in Windows 7 that's nonexistent in Windows 10.

Comment: Instead of "taskbar icons", better use "notification area / systray" in the subject - however according to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/61dawi/identical_taskbars_on_both_monitors/) this currently is not possible.

Comment: @Furty I tried to stick to the official name, but good suggestion. Added for clarification. And thanks for the link. That's pretty sad. 

Answer (score 4):

<s>I believe you need to open the Settings app and then go to **Personalisation** > **Taskbar**. Scroll down to **Multiple displays**, and flick the switch that says "Show taskbar on all displays". Check that the "Show taskbar buttons on" dropdown is set to "All taskbars" so that the icons show on all displays.</s>

I don't think there is a way to get the system tray to show up on all displays. According to [Addictivetips](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-showhide-taskbar-on-multiple-displays-in-windows-10/):

> There still isn’t support for getting the system tray to show up on multiple displays

And according to the second-to-last answer on [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/notification-area-on-all-display/a68731e4-905c-4a1a-9b59-c530b4651dea):

> Currently, having a notification area option for both taskbar is not available.

However, things may have changed since April 2017. There may be a registry tweak or something that you could use? I certainly can't find anything.

Comment: This is a setting for the buttons (pinned and running applications), not the icons (sound, network, battery etc.).

Comment: Oh! Thanks for clarifying. I have updated my post with what I can find. (Not that it'll be very useful...)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's only currently possible with third party software.

One of these is [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/), which has both a free and paid version, but the feature which allows the system tray to be shown in the taskbars of other monitors are only in the paid version.

Disclaimer: I'm in no way involved with these software, I just found them while I was looking for solutions to the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

i am having the same issue.
It is very puzzling why this is not possible, my second monitor is a wacom cintiq.
i need the touchkeyboard on it but there is no way to activate it without the systemtray.
i can only do that from my primary monitor, but since i have a physical keyboard directly under that, i don't need it there.
Yet i can't make the Wacom my primary because its not always on.
just a normal taskbar icon, instead of the systray one, to start the touchkeyboard would help...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).